# Writing CSV file having the names of dictionaries in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, loops, csv, dictionary

Maybe it is a simple question but I can't find a similar one elsewhere.

I have a list of dictionaries like

```py
all_dictionaries=[dictio1, dictio2, dictio3]
```

And I would like to save those dictionaries to different CSV files with each file having the name of the dictionaries like: `dictio1.csv`, `dictio2.csv`, `dictio3.csv`

So far I have written this code, but looping over a list of dictionaries meaning looping over the items of the general `all_dictionaries`. The problem is in the filename variable where it doesn't recognize the dictionary as a string but rather as a dictionary. Any idea how to get the name of the dictionary and place it as a file name?

```py
for dictio in all_dictionaries:
    filename="%s.csv" %dictio
    with open(filename, 'wb') as csv_file:
        writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
        for key, value in dictio.items():
            writer.writerow([key, value])
```

Comment: At runtime, Python doesn't have a simple way to map a structure in memory back to a variable name. There could be several variables pointing to the same structure. You will need to change your code so that the name you want to use is saved explicitly somewhere.

Comment: On the other hand, it's easy to go from a string to the variable with the same name; if that's acceptable, it should be easy to find a duplicate. (Hint: `locals`)

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the "variable name" as filename here. Maybe you should have a name key that has a filename as value in all of your dictionaries and then you can do a loop like...

```
for dictio in all_dictionnaries:
    filename="%s.csv" %dictio['name']
    with open(filename, 'wb') as csv_file:
        writer=csv.writer(csv_file)
        for key, value in dictio.items():
            writer.writerow([key, value])
```

This may get tedious when you have lots of dicts to handle. But i think this should work if you have small number of dicts.